# How do I modify the -encoding argument to javac in the Android Ant build system

Tags: android

Apologies if this is a stupid question - I'm an Android and Ant newbie.

I have utf8 encoded source files that I need to compile with the Android Ant build system. By default, the encoding is set to ascii. I'd be very grateful for a pointer to whatever I need to do to let the build system know that my files are utf8.

Incidentally, it works fine if I build in Eclipse, but I need to build from the command line.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `java.encoding=UTF-8` to **build.properties**

Comment: Thanks Alexander. As it happens, we have ended up modifying all our source files to use escape sequences instead of UTF-8 characters, so no longer need to do this, but this does look like it would have solved our problem!

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at android-sdk-windows\platforms[your-platform]\ant\ant_rules_r2.xml. You can find

```
<javac encoding="ascii" ...
```

line there and I guess you can change it.

Comment: Any changes to installed platform image are bad - they will be lost on update. ANT allows to overwrite any properties with project-local files. In fact, this file does not exist anymore in recent SDK